# C# - Oracle Dates Different on Desktop vs Server

Tags: c#, oracle, windows-server-2016

I'm running windows 10 and recently updated my MVC app from 32 bit to 64 bit, including the Oracle client.

I installed ODAC1931_x64 on my machine and am using this nuget:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/

When I run the app on my desktop, everything works fine. I can pass dates to my DB packages like so:

```
comm.Parameters.Add(Constants.DATABASE_PARAMETERS.FIELDS.START_DATE, OracleDbType.Date).Value = startDate;
```

And in the DB package the date come through as:

```
25-NOV-20
```

I installed the same ODAC on the server, Windows 2016, and moved my app to it. But when I run it, the date is showing up on the DB as:

```
20-11-25
```

And now the DB package is throwing the error:

```
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

This did not happen when I was on 32 bit Oracle, the date came through as 25-NOV-20, it only happens with the 64 bit client and only on the server, not my desktop.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: When you specify ` OracleDbType.Date).Value = startDate` then `startDate` should be a `DateTime` value, rather than a **string**

Comment: Yes, it is a datetime variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are relying on implicit date conversion in order to display it and enter it as a string. You need to use conversion functions with explicit date formats in order to be safe.

Eg. `to_char(my_date_column,'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')` if you want to display a date as a string
`to_date('25/11/2020 21:00:00','hh24:mi:ss')` if you have a string and want to set a date column.

Remember 2 digit years are why every software engineer worked around the clock coming up to the year 2000. Always use 4 digits.